# How to play a sound regularly with timer_tick?

Tags: c#, .net, forms, winforms, timer

How to play sound in a timer? Or is there a alternative way to do this? I want to do play a short sound in every 20 minutes.
My code can show a message box in a timer with normally, or can play sound with a button. But can't play a sound in a timer.

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Windows.Forms;
using System.Runtime.InteropServices;
using System.Media;

namespace Eye
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {

        System.Media.SoundPlayer player = new System.Media.SoundPlayer(@"C:\Users\user\Desktop\Sounds\sound.wav");

        public int makroButon;
        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }
        private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            timer1.Interval = 6000;
        }
        private void radioButton1_Checked(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            timer1.Start();
        }

        private void timer1_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            player.Play();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Are you sure that the Timer is actually started, that the `Timer.Tick` event is actually wired to the `timer1_Tick` handler and that your sound file is a PCM wav format?

Comment: If i put a MessageBox.Show command inside of timer1_Tick, it's working regularly. And if i try to play the sound with a button, it's playing too. I also tried to play it in another function and just call the function from timer1_Tick but still didn't play.

Comment: Make an experiment: remove the Timer1 component from the Form Designer and also its `Tick` handler. Add `System.Windows.Forms.Timer playerTimer = null;` near the `player` Field definition. In Form.Load, add: `playerTimer = new System.Windows.Forms.Timer() { Interval = 5000 }; playerTimer.Tick += (o, a) => player.Play(); playerTimer.Start();`. Start the Project to open up Form1.

Comment: I found the solution... This code wasn'tn working because Form1_load was doing nothing... So timer's interval was still 100... I changed it from Design page and it worked. Thanks for your answers my friend.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I created Form1_Load manually. So  `timer1.Interval = 6000;` line didn't work. Probably 100ms wasn't enough to play a sound. For create a form1_load function don't type it manually, just click double to an empty place from design page. And it will be named like **"Form1_Load_1"**, not like *"Form1_Load"*.

Comment: ...or you could properly wire up the existing method to the Load() event.  Click on the Form, then in the Properties Pane click the lighting bolt icon to switch to events.  Now find the Load() event in the list and change the dropdown arrow to the right to the existing method "Form1_Load".

Comment: Ooh yes. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

So I think your main issue is that a radio button isn't the correct control to be using looking for a check. I used a checkbox and it seems to work. I also explicitly made the timer in code and set the event handler for tick.

```
    SoundPlayer player;
    private Timer timer1;

    public int makroButon;
    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        player = new System.Media.SoundPlayer(@"C:\path\sound.wav");
        timer1 = new Timer();
        timer1.Tick += Timer1_Tick;
    }

    private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        timer1.Interval = 6000;
    }

    private void Timer1_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        player.Play();
    }

    private void CheckBox1_CheckedChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if(sender is CheckBox cb)
        {
            if (cb.Checked)
            {
                timer1.Start();
            }
            else
            {
                timer1.Stop();
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: You missed the comments. The OP finally found out that the Load event was never subscribed to. The *phantom Handler* was added manually and never actually *wired up*.